# Sitefinity - Create a new Blog Post

Tags: sitefinity

We are trying out Sitefinity as a possible solution for creating a simple blog.  It was simple to create a site, but now I need my users to be able to add their own blog posts without having to log into the admin site.

What are we not seeing?  Do we have to write custom code to allow a registered user to add a blog or a blog post?  I've seen documentation on how to do this, but I would think there would be a setting that you just need to change.

Thanks in advance,

Randy

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are attempting to accomplish, as the main interface for creating blog posts lives in the backend.

One option you could explore is using Windows Live Writer, which is supported by Sitefinity to allow your users to blog from outside Sitefinity. They still need a backend account to authenticate them, but WLW will take care of publishing it through the API.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I'm looking for a way for users to add new posts. They can add comments, but we need them to be able to add new posts. There seems to be two ways to do this. Via the Admin screen and tools such as Live Writer. What about just being able to click a button on the Blog page that says "Add New Blog Post", similiar to "Add Comment". We have a defined number of users that we want to be able to add a new post and others can comment. Maybe even a smaller group can add a new blog.

Comment: you could create a user control that inputs text for the various blog fields (Title, Content, Summary, etc) then use the Blogs API (http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/blogs/managing-blog-posts/creating-blog-posts) to create them.

Answer (score 0):

As an administrator, you can create users and assign them built-in roles such as author, editor and administrator. You can edit the permissions of these built-in roles to allow or disallow rights to various features, such as posting to a blog.  You can also build custom roles if that suits your purpose and assign them to your users.

Comment: I think He is talking about API ...I'm still looking arounf but I found there is 3 ways to achieve it.
1. SiteFinity API -->  to MVC JSON Web services
2. Fluent API -->  to MVC JSON Web services
3. Calling SVC service layer directly